# my lib/collections.js loading but not being called in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/prototyping-with-meteor/

This is my structure

```
 chat
 |_client
 |  |_chat.html
 |  |_chat.js
 |   
 |_lib
    |_collections.js
```

in colletions.js I'm doing

var Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');

```
if (Meteor.isServer && Rooms.find().count() == 0) {
  var rooms = [
    {name: 'Meteor Talk', members: 3, last_activity: '1 minute ago',
      messages: [
        {author: 'Tom', text: 'Hi there Sacha!'},
        {author: 'Sacha', text: 'Hey Tom, how are you?'},
        {author: 'Tom', text: 'Good thanks!'},
      ]},
    {name: 'Meteor Development', members: 2, last_activity: '5 minutes ago'},
    {name: 'Meteor Core', members: 0, last_activity: '3 days ago'}
  ]

  _.each(rooms, function(room) {
    Rooms.insert(room);
  });
}
```

And in chat.js

```
Template.rooms.helpers({
  rooms: function() { return Rooms.find(); }
});
```

I'm getting the error `Rooms is not defined`, if i debug, i see that the folder lib/collections.js is loading, but is not being called.

Am i missing something in my code or configuration ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful about using `var`. In Meteor variables are scoped to a file, so when you define `var Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');` it is accessible only in `lib/collections.js`. This helps to keep code clean and uncluttered.

To make it accessible all over with a global variable scope, remove the `var`:

```
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');
```

Comment: Wow that was it! this is something that should have been mentionned somewhere! Thank you